# Can't call showing modal on condition

Tags: jquery

I want to call congrats Bootstrap modal on condition: call show modal when some notice text is showing.

Condition is correct. I tried it with simple alerts and everything worked.

Here is my code:

```
   if ( $('.alert').text() == 'Signed in successfully.' ) {
 $('#congrats').show();
    }
```

Here is my html :

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="congrats">
```

There is no errors in browser's console.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: check whether it goes inside that if-condition. Try putting some `alert('something')` inside the if-condition. Must be a minor issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, for some reason I found that syntax has changed or I missed it. Here is working variant:

```
  if ( $('.alert').text() == 'Signed in successfully.' ) {
    $('#congrats').modal('show')
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some spaces included in $(".alert").text(), so try jquery trim and use as follows

```
if ($.trim($('.alert').text()) == 'Signed in successfully.') {
  $('#congrats').show(); // or $('#congrats').model("show"); as per the recent comment
}
```

Good Luck !!